# prove $\dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{range}(\sqrt{T^*T}))$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, isometry

I'm a student and I'm studying linear algebra. in **Polar Decomposition** we have:

> for a linear operator $T$, there exist a linear isometry $S$ that:
>   $$ T =S\sqrt{T^*T}$$

so if $S$ is a linear transformation then it must be $\dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) \leq  \dim(\operatorname{range}(\sqrt{T^*T}))$.

But why?

**edit:** I think it must be equal, I mean:

$$\dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{range}(\sqrt{T^*T}))$$

I know that $\dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{range}(T^*))$ but because of the square root I cannot prove that $\dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{range}(\sqrt{T^*T}))$.

Comment: If $f\colon U\to V$ and $g\colon V\to W$ are linear maps, then the rank of $g\circ f$ cannot be greater than the ranks of $g$ and $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @egreg pointed out, for any linear maps $S,T$, the rank of $ST$ is always less than or equal to that of $T$. To see this, note that by dimension theorem $$\dim \text{ran} L =\dim \operatorname{dom} L-\dim\ker L\le\dim \operatorname{dom} L$$ for any linear map $L$. Now, the image of $ST$ can be seen as the image of
$$
S\big|_{\text{ran} T} :\text{ran} T\to V,
$$ we can see that $\dim \text{ran} (ST)\le \dim \text{ran} T$ as wanted. Moreover, equality holds if $\dim \ker S\big|_{\text{ran}T}=\dim [\ker S\cap\text{ran}T]=0$. (Here, $V$ denotes the vector space where $S,T$ are defined.)

To see that $\dim \text{ran}T =\dim \text{ran}(T^*T)$, note that $Tx = 0$ if and only if $T^*Tx =0$, which is saying that $\ker T = \ker (T^*T)$. Now, by dimension theorem, we have
$$
\dim \text{ran} T = \dim V - \dim \ker T = \dim V - \dim \ker (T^*T) = \dim\text{ran}(T^*T).
$$ (Or we can use the fact that $S$ is an isometry.)

Answer (score 1):

If $T\colon U\to V$ and $S\colon V\to W$ are linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces, then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}
\dim\range{ST}\le\dim\range(T)
$$
This follows from the rank-nullity theorem:
\begin{align}
\dim U&=\dim\range(T)+\dim\ker(T) \\
\dim U&=\dim\range(ST)+\dim\ker(ST)
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\dim\range(ST)=\dim\range(T)+\dim\ker(T)-\dim\ker(ST)\le\dim\range(T)
$$
because from $\ker(T)\subseteq\ker(ST)$ we have $\dim\ker(T)\le\dim\ker(ST)$.

In your case you can conclude that
$$
\dim\range(T)\le\dim\range(\sqrt{T^*T})
$$
On the other hand, $S$ is an isometry, so it is invertible and
$$
\sqrt{T^*T}=S^{-1}T
$$
The same argument as before implies
$$
\dim\range(\sqrt{T^*T})\le\dim\range(T)
$$